# Change Asset user in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay

I would like to change the owner (user) of an asset from code in Liferay. It works well for Webcontent, with `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateArticle()`, if I set a different user id, the user is changed.
But for Documents and Media, with `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry()`, LR does not change the user in AssetEntry table.

I also tried updating directly the asset using `AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(long userId, long groupId, String className, long classPK, long[] categoryIds, String[] tagNames)` , but it has no effect on the user.

Any ideas to solve this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have found a solution:

```
AssetEntry asset = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.getEntry(DLFileEntry.class.getName(), fileEntry.getPrimaryKey());
asset.setUserId(newUser);
asset.setUserName(newUserName);
AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateAssetEntry(asset);
```

Interestingly this way it is working.